# Spyder 5.3.2 NameError on local modules when modules have been defined

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, spyder, nameerror

I'm using Spyder 5.3.2 from a new environment through Anaconda, but I'm getting weird name errors on code that did work when I still used 5.1.5. My code looks something like the following:

```
import Report_Initialisation as ri
import Report_Execute as re
import Perform_Analysis as pa
import Create_Visuals as cv

name = "John Smith"
df_wanted_report_parts = ri.read_template(name)    # No error here, reads info from an excel template

# No error here, Report_Execute module contains several runcell commands that run specific 
# cells in this script depending on which parts of the report are needed
re.execute_analysis_cells(df_wanted_report_parts)

#%% Execute analysis
df_analyzed = pa.run_analysis(name)

#%% Execute visuals
cv.create_scatterplot(df_analyzed)

#####################################################

NameError: name 'pa' is not defined
NameError: name'cv' is not defined
```

Sorry if it's a bit cryptic, but that's basically what's happening. The issue isn't with the imports, because it's working for reading the template and executing the cells. Any idea what might be causing this?

**Edit**

I've worked it out slightly, but am still not sure on a solution to the problem. I believe that, since the cells are being run through another script, it's not remembering the variables defined in the main script. For example, importing Perform_Analysis and Create_Visuals in the Report_Execute script as well means the NameError is no longer on pa and cv, but on the name variable. I suppose I could pass this variable to the execute_analysis_cells function, but in reality there's a lot more variables like this and dataframes being created along the way, so this isn't a super good solution. Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please go to the menu entry`Run > Configuration per file` and enable there the option called `Run in console's namespace instead of an empty one`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't :(. I've set the option in both files, and in the general options as well but I still get the NameErrors.

Comment: Is this something that was working for you on a previous Spyder version? Could it be possible for you to downgrade to Spyder 5.3.1 and check if that problem happens there?

Comment: Yea it worked on 5.1.5 (the anaconda version), I tried 5.3.1 as well but the same problem persisted. We've solved the issue now by having everything in the same script. Not as elegant, but it works!